# Musescore: how to do 8th notes with 16th note triplets

Tags: musescore

[image]

So I need help creating these 8th notes with 16th note triplets, the tempo is 4/4. So far, I've tried using the triplet button but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for. Got any suggestions?

Comment: I posted an answer by making some assumptions, but you may want to clarify what have you got that is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Edit your post to show what you got in your .mscz file.

Comment: There is also a plugin easing that process: you can enter three sixteenth notes and then press the tuplet button and it makes a triplet out of it (and vice-versa): [Duration Editor](https://musescore.org/en/project/duration-editor) (working only in MuseScore 3.6 or 3.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entering tuplets in musescore is slightly non-intuitive, because you need to start with the note value corresponding to the length of the whole tuplet.

3 sixteenth note triplet notes sum up to an eight note. So in note input mode you need to select eight note, and then click on tuplet icon, and select triplet (hotkey is Ctrl-3). This will also change the input note value to a sixteenth note. Then you can input three of those notes.